# Are polyglot microservices (multiple technologies) more secure than using a single technology framework?

Tags: attacks, attack-surface

As a full-stack cloud-native (AWS, Azure, and GCP) polyglot (Rust, Golang, Python, and Java) microservices developer, the nagging question that I have is if the use of multiple technology frameworks vs single language (e.g., Java) have increased and improved the overall security posture?

Overall, is it more secure to use a single language/technology/framework or to use multiple language/technology/framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless the language itself has its specific pitfalls regarding security it mainly matters how fluent the developers are with the respective language, how much they understand they concepts necessary for security and how good they are capable they are to apply this knowledge into a secure by design software.

If there are multiple experts in their respective languages and if the tasks can clearly be separated it might be more secure to use multiple languages since the relevant expertise is (unfortunately) spread over multiple developers and languages. But apart from that a multi-language approach likely causes increased complexity of the code, makes it harder to understand and harder to maintain and limits the reuse of components - which typically makes the software less secure. So it would be preferred to stay with a single language as long as there is sufficient expertise for this available.

That said, there are some problems which are easier to solve in one language than in another. Since this also impacts the complexity and maintainability of the software the focus should also be to use the language which best fits the problem.

Comment: thanks! Assuming ceteris paribus, 2 developers, one who is extremely skilled in java and the security aspects of java vs one who is skilled in multiple languages but less so in the security nuances in the different language (a logical tradeoff), as an software architect, should he/she dictate both developers to build in a single language or multiple language with the goal of building a more secure solution? (assuming speed isnt an issue.)

Comment: @NathanAw: I would recommend that they should use both the same language and that the developer familiar with the security aspects reviews the changes by the less knowledgeable one and this way also teaches the other the relevant security parts. Otherwise large parts of the code would be written w/o properly addressing security in the design and w/o someone knowledgeable in security able to review and maintain code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question which I can't answer in general, but I'll give a specific example of where a polyglot environment opens up security holes that would not be there in a homogenous environment.

Consider this network setup:

```
Internet --||DMZ||--> Front-end web app --||DMZ||--> Backend business logic web app --> Database
```

Assume that the `Front-end web app` and `Backend business logic web app` are both your code. The question here is whether they are written in the same language / technology, or different.

Now consider a vulnerability like this:

> [CVE-2017-8046](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2017-8046)
>
> Malicious PATCH requests submitted to servers using Spring Data REST versions prior to 2.6.9 (Ingalls SR9), versions prior to 3.0.1 (Kay SR1) and Spring Boot versions prior to 1.5.9, 2.0 M6 can use specially crafted JSON data to run arbitrary Java code.

If both of your webservers on on the same technology (java / Spring), then this malicious payload will detonate on the frond-end web app, giving the attacker control over a server in the DMZ. Bad, but not nearly as bad as if the front-end was, say Rust and forwarded the malicious PATCH message to the backend where it detonated giving the attacker control of a backend machine with direct access to the database.

This is a bit of a contrived example as your stack has to be set up in a very specific way with very specific behaviours (forwarding crafted message) for this example to work, but I have come across examples like this in the wild. There may also be examples where polyglot protects you against an attack, so my answer here is not conclusive either way. Security is hard.